# Switching power to Stepper Motor Drive using relay and arduino

Tags: power, relay, stepper-motor, switching

1.This project involves use of stepper motor once in 5 mins to perform precise movement.I m driving the Stepper using L298N-L297 Stepper Motor Driver Board and Arduino UNO. Since the Stepper Motor creates lot of noise when it is not moving but is powered due to the resisting torque , I want to switch off the power to the driver board when not in use . I have used a 5V relay for this purpose as shown in the circuit. But this is creating a short and Arduino is turning off.Please advice and suggest what is wrong with this approach and any alternate solutions

2.Is this problem due to the common ground between arduino , relay , stepper driver and the 24V supply?

[image: circuit Used]

[image: 5V Relay board]

[image: Stepper Motor Driver]

Comment: Check the battery polarity on that schematic!

Comment: No need to remove power to the drive. Just use the ENABLE (EN) pin to the L297.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the circuit you're drawing, you connect +24V to GND of the Arduino to GND of the stepper motor tot GND of the 24V battery...

That would explain your issue.

The 24V should be connected only to the terminals of the relais, not to any other curcuit.

Comment: My bad i should have used ground line of 24V supply to be connected through NO and COM of the 5V relay. But shouldn't the GND of Stepper Drive be connected to GND of ARDUINO board for them to function properly?

Comment: Also the GND terminal for the Supply Voltage on Driver board is connected to  the GND terminal of the 5V-GND o/ps available after the regulator on the board.So should all the GNDs of the boards and supplies be kept common or not ??

Comment: From what i know of electronics, you share GND between the circuits unless you want complete insulation of the circuits.

A relay or optocopler can be used if you require insulation, but in your case you only need the relay to switch on that +24V line, so this shouldn't be a problem.

the +24V of the supply should go to the one conector of the relay, the other connector of the relay should go to +24V of your board.  You should research whether your board can cope with input on +5V lines but no +24V connected

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I got another solution - Connect the GND line of the 24V supply goes to the COM of relay and NO of the relay goes to GND of the driver board. This way there will be no shorting of the 24V line to the GND of Arduino and also when relay is ON , it provides common GND to all circuits.Also that extra GND connection from the 5V O/P on Driver to the Arduino should not be made.

Comment: I found a much simpler solution to this problem, without using relays. Just pull the enable pin on the stepper driver board low. It switches off the power to the motor.